# XsdToHaskell output usage

Tags: xml, haskell, xsd, haxml

I have generated Haskell data types from XSD using the XsdToHaskell tool embedded in the HaXml library.
And now I have a bunch of data types and seem-to-be parsers for those datatypes.
But the main function in the output file (`elementPlans`) is returning `XMLParser PlansType` (`PlansType` is the type of the root element in XML) and I have no idea how to parse the XML file having this parser.

Here's [Plans.hs](http://pastebin.com/m6Qzsd8t) (output of XmlToHaskell), [XSD](http://pastebin.com/SH8vZfe3) and [XML](http://pastebin.com/7zQFteZJ).

Comment: Have you made any attempts whatsoever so far? (including failed and partial ones)

Comment: Well, I found [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.22.4/src/src/tools/XsdToHaskell.hs) of XsdToHaskell and the comment on the top suggests to _"import Xsd2Haskell wherever you intend to read and write XML files with your Haskell programs"_ but I can't find that module.
Also, `runParser` sais that `Parser x a` is not compatible with `XMLParser PlansType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves the problem:

```
xmlText <- readFile fname
let (Document _ _ root _) = xmlParse "(No Document)" xmlText
let (Right plans) = fst $ runParser elementPlans [CElem root noPos]
```

In the first line we read xml file content as string, then `xmlParse` returns document with root element of type `Element` which we use to create single token of type `CElem` and then run parser, generated by XsdToHaskell.

Answer (score 0):

Having done some searching on [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=XMLParser), it seems that `XMLParser PlansType` is the same as `Parser (Content Posn) PlansType`:

```
type XMLParser a = Parser (Content Posn) a
```

according to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.25.3/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-XmlContent-Parser.html#t:XMLParser.

Which in turn lead me to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse-1.11/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Poly-Plain.html (and [the lazy version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse-1.11/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Poly-Lazy.html) thereof) — which has a `runParser` function.

---

Re: your comment: the types in the documentation are clickable, i.e. you can navigate to them and try to understand them:

clicking on `Content` takes you [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.25.3/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-XmlContent-Parser.html#t:Content). From there it's obvious that in order to pass in a `String` (`[t]` where `t ~ Char`), you need to construct a `Content` value using `CString Bool CharData i`. The bool specifies whether whitespace is significant; `CharData` is an alias for `String`, and the `i` is a value of type `Posn` in your case.

In order to construct a `Posn` value, click on [Posn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.25.3/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Posn.html#t:Posn); you'll see there's a function `noPos` which you can use to construct a value of type `Posn` (assuming you don't care about locations in error reporting for the time being).

All in all: `CString False "bla bla bla" noPos` or `CString True "bla bla bla" noPos` should get you started.

Comment: I have tried that, but I got baffled on token sequence that `runParser` is taking as an argument:
`runParser :: Parser t a -> [t] -> (Either String a, [t])`
So, according to this:
`type XMLParser a = Parser (Content Posn) a`
I should pass something of type like this:
`[Content Posn]`, but I didn't understand how do I get that...

Comment: Firstly I'd like to mention that rudeness is not necessary. I'm getting quite lost in documentation since it's very poor and I'm not an expert in Haskell.
Secondly, how to construct a `Content Posn` value is not a solution - I need to tokenize input document because runparser is expecting "<Plans>" as first token and so on. Is there any function to do that for me?

Comment: mine + user5402's answers should then solve both problems?

Comment: `xmlLex` is doing not exactly what `runParser` is expecting. For instance, tag `<Plans>` will be tokenized as "<", "Plans" and ">", when parser is expecting "<Plans>". Also it is having troubles with "<?xml version=...".

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the `htmlParse'` routine in module Text.XML.HaXml.Html.Parse for ideas:

```
-- | The first argument is the name of the file, the second is the string
--   contents of the file.  The result is the generic representation of
--   an XML document.  Any parsing errors are returned in the @Either@ type.
htmlParse' :: String -> String -> Either String (Document Posn)
htmlParse' file = Prelude.either Left (Right . simplify) . fst
                  . runParser document . xmlLex file
```

It looks like the `xmlLex` function is used to tokenize a String and then `runParser` is used to for parsing.

In that module, `document` has type:

```
document :: HParser (Document Posn)
type HParser a = Parser (Posn,TokenT) a
```

which looks like it uses the same `Parser` type that `XMLParser` uses.